# updating subtotal when products added to cart

Tags: magento

I am currently adding products programatically to the cart, to create a 'free sample' aspect to my site.

Currently, all of these products are $0 and you can add a maximum of 15. Once you have 5 'free sample' products in the cart, I need to add $20 to the subtotal.

I know I can get the grandtotal using:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
```

But how do I access the subtotal and also add $20 to it?

I'm guessing I'll need to write an observer, as I'll need to check when products are added/removed from the cart in order to either add the $20 or not.

Has anyone done this before or could point me in the right direction of how I could do this?

Many thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually answered this question recently here is a basic idea of what needs to be done, let me know if you need more specific details:
Add an observer which looks for this event 'sales_quote_add_item':

```
<events>
    <sales_quote_add_item>
        <observers>
            <priceupdate_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                <method>updatePrice</method>
            </priceupdate_observer>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_add_item>
```

The observer should have a method which does something like this:

```
public function updatePrice($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
    if(sample etc...) $new_price = <insert logic>
    $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
    $quote_item->save();
}
```

Comment: Where am i adding the xml? `Mage/Checkout/etc/config.xml`? I have not created an observer before

Comment: The xml tag goes inside the global tag in the config, and the function would go in your observer file within the Model folder. Here is a link on how to build up and observer http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Comment: Would this be automatically called when each of the sample products are added/removed? Would this also update the subtotal when 10 sample products have been added?

Comment: This even 'sales_quote_add_item' will be added when a product is added to cart which is when magento creates quotes you would need to check if this item is a sample based on attribute of the sku $quote_item->getSku(); for removing you would need to call the event 'sales_quote_remove_item'

Comment: I am checking if the product is a sample by it's price. all samples are $0, so that should be ok. The problem so far, is that observer is called when a product is added. I need to be able to check if more than 5 have been added and then add $20 to the subtotal. I'm guessing the subtotal is calculated based on the quote items. How would the $20 be added? I only want to add $20 to the subtotal, not to each product

Comment: Try this event: checkout_cart_save_after

Comment: Yes instead. This more of a one time event, but you will need to loop through all the items in order to check for samples...

Comment: Ok, I have done that. I think what I'm going to do is. When the count gets to 5, then that product will be $20. All others will be $0. This means that the subtotal will update

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this slightly wrong, total is calculated over item prices you have in quote and "total" is not just something that you can add or subtract from like you wish to.

for your current task i'd suggest you to create a shopping cart rule "add x get n for free"